# Yikes! How did I earn 300 reputation yesterday if a user can only earn 200 reputation a day?

Tags: support, reputation

The *Reputation* tab of my user profile looks like this:
[image: what!?!? +300 rep yesterday?]
However, according to the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), a user may only earn 200 reputation a day.

So why did I earn 300 reputation in a day?

Comment: Another example of rep not counting toward the 200 limit is the association bonus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certain reputation-gathering actions are exempt from the 200 per day cap.

The most common one is the award of bounties.  Any bounty received is not counted towards the 200.  However, in your case, this isn't the reason.

You had a question migrated here from Superuser:- [Why did SMARTDRV have to be started with /x when DOS started?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/19982/276).  This had already acquired reputation on Superuser:- [Why did SMARTDRV have to be started with /x when DOS started?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/19982/276).

When [migrated](https://superuser.com/posts/1652418/revisions%20) the reputation comes with it, and doesn't count towards the daily cap on the target site.

Migration is best explained on main meta:- [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/236563) that post is also the guide for moderators on when to - and not to - migrate a question.